# How do I query the Elasticsearch API for messages containing a certain string?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am attempting to query Elasticsearch for all of the logs that contain the string 'DEBUG' within _source of each log. How would I go about this using curl XGET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/_search?pretty&q=DEBUG'
```

Comment: Is it possible to search all indexes?